# The structure of the clause "go all round Italy, Austria, Switzerland"

Tags: sentence-structure, modifiers

> He's going all round Italy, Austria, Switzerland.

Would you tell me if my parsing is right or not?

"all round" is complement of "go" and "Italy, Austria, Switzerland" are complement of "all round"
(the head of "all round" is *round*, *all* being premodifier of *round*)

Comment: "All around Italy, Austria and Switzerland" is a preposition phrase headed by "round" with "all" as an adjunct. the PP functions as a complement of "going".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the prepositional phrase "all around" is used to indicate that the subject will be travelling throughout Italy, Austria, and Switzerland. And you are correct that "all" is modifying "round", specifying that the subject will be going to many/all different parts of the named countries (as opposed to visiting just a few parts of each). Common phrases that are synonymous with "all around" in this context would include: "throughout" and "all over".

Comment: To complete the parse, it would have been helpful to mention that the PP functions as complement of "going"